# How to use a HOC with a class Component

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I've spend the last couple of hours looking at how to render this but i can't get my head around it.

```js
const Test = props => (
  <p>
    {console.log(props)}
    {props.children}
  </p>
)

const changeColor = WrappedComponent => props => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent style={{ color: props.color }} test="adasd">
          {props.children}
        </WrappedComponent>
      )
    }
  }
}

const Temp = changeColor(Test)
```

When i go to render it it tells me that `Functions are not valid as a React child.` How would i return a Class Component as i need to have access to state.

Comment: I don't think you can render a `console.log`

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the reply. If i do this `const Var = Temp("test")` then i get it to render. Does that mean that i always have to double invoke the  function, i.e. `Temp && Var` do get class components to render? If so that seems to be a little much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `changeColor` is

`function that return function that returns class component`

To make your code work you would need to:

```
const props = {};

const Temp = changeColor(Test)(props)
```

However, I think you don't need that function with props as an argument:

```
const changeColor = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent style={{ color: this.props.color }} test="adasd">
          {this.props.children}
        </WrappedComponent>
      )
    }
  }
}

const Temp = changeColor(Test)
```

Comment: You literally saved me! I've spent more time that i care to admit on this! Just to confirm, HOC, they don't return a `new` component but rather they just alter the one you passed in?

Comment: @StrahinjaAjvaz, HOCs do return a new component

Comment: @StrahinjaAjvaz HOC is a function that returns a Component. That's it. But HOC's more or less give you the ability to reuse javascript scoping and configure passed component.

Comment: question, why can't we use a functional component for an HOC. I mean the class does nohing but render and we do not use its state

Comment: @akshaykishore good question. I think you can use function component. Now with hooks it's even easier